# Android : How to Customize webview like i phone (see image)

Tags: android, webview

can we achieve webview functionality like i phone in android ?

see bottom part of image..[image]

you can see bottom bar having next,back and reload functionality. also with custom background ?

Answer will be appreciate greatly.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What did you do so far? Did you check the Android ActionBar component? It can also be set to split at the top and bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the bottom and top bar should be out of webView and the reload forward ,etc should be buttons. you will have the webView in the center . That's how it will work

Comment: SO have provided the functionality of commenting so its better to use it. It should be in comment.